# Expected value versus mean value

Tags: statistics

What is the difference between the expected value and mean value of a discrete random variable or discrete uniform distribution?

Comment: The difference is $0$.

Comment: I think they are synonymous. Didn't you mean (no pun intended) "the difference between the mean and the median"?